# Display all the data from the product table with translations, but if there is no translation for the product, display it with the default language

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables

products:

[image]

product_translations:

[image]

```php
$locale = 'de';

  \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('products')
            ->leftJoin('product_translations', 'product_translations.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->where('product_translations.locale' , '=', $locale)
            ->get()
```

How do I get this result?

[image]

Comment: `...->where('product_translations.locale' , '=', $locale)->value('name');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I would do something like this:

```
$locale = 'de';
$default = 'en';

$products = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('products')
            ->leftJoin('product_translations as preferred_locale', function($join) use($locale) {
                $join
                    ->on('product_translations.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                    ->where('locale', $locale);
            })
            ->leftJoin('product_translations as default_locale', function($join) use ($default) {
                $join
                    ->on('product_translations.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                    ->where('locale', $default);
            })
            //Select all product fields, and both locale fields.
            ->selectRaw('products.*, preferred_locale.name as locale_name, default_locale.name as default_name') 
            ->get();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    //Use coalescing operator(??) to set/select the translation
    $translation = $product->locale_name ?? $product->default_name;
}
```